# Adding a tool window to an exisiting VS extension package - FindToolWindow fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-package

I have a VS package with no tool windows, and now I want to add a first tool window to it. This is what I've done:

1. Created an empty class derived from ToolWindowPane.
2. Added Guid attribute to this class. I've generated a new GUID with the Visual Studio built-in tool.
3. Added 2 attributes to the main package class:
   `[ProvideToolWindow(typeof(MainToolWindow))]`
   and
   `([ProvideToolWindowVisibility(typeof(MainToolWindow), VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionExists_string)]`
4. Called `ToolWindowPane MyWindow = this.FindToolWindow(typeof(MainToolWindow), 0, true);`

This results in an exception:

> Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF
>   (E_UNEXPECTED))

What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception was caused by content being null. Adding this to the window constructor does the trick:

```
Content = new System.Windows.Controls.UserControl();
```